# POST JSON method does not work when project has been exported to WEBGL and uploaded to firebase hosting

Tags: unity, client-server, json, http

I have a database set up on firebase and when i run my game in the unity edtitor and as a standalone exported Windows .exe file, the call gets made correctly to the database and JSON data gets posted correctly. However when I export the exact same project to WEBGL and upload it to my firebase hosting server, the JSON call does not work. Here is my code, could someone please help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class GameOverMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
 public InputField nameInputField;

 public void MainMenu()
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
 }

 public void SubmitScore()
 {
     StartCoroutine(SendScore());
     SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
 }
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {

 }



 public IEnumerator SendScore()
 {
     Scoreboard s = new Scoreboard(nameInputField.text, PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score"), PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Seed"));
     Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
     Hashtable data = new Hashtable();
     data.Add("name", s.Name);
     data.Add("score", s.Score);
     data.Add("seed", s.Seed);

     UnityHTTP.Request postRequest = new UnityHTTP.Request("post", "https://alexclearythesisgame.firebaseio.com/Scoreboard.json", data);
     postRequest.Send();
     yield return postRequest.isDone;
 }

}
```

Comment: Check https://answers.unity.com/questions/898360/http-request-over-an-https-webgl.html I believe you must configure first some cross domain access, never done that myself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment . I actually found a solution and will be posting it below . It had something to do with dll files and unity webgl so I had to use the following rest api : https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient/blob/master/README.md . Thanks for the comment as it reminded me to update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the following free rest api as with the current package I was using , webgl wasn’t transferring the .dlls correctly :
https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient/blob/master/README.md